# Swapping External to Internal Memory

Tags: internal-storage

I have swapped my external to internal memory by using the app external2internal after rooting my Samsung Galaxy Core i8262. And it went wrong! I want to revert back my previous original state. Is there any option? How to get my original previous condition, Not to swap anymore! Please help me anyone!

Answer (score 0):

just tick the reset at boot box and reboot your phone,i switch between the state you in and original state all the time.